# mysqldump a zipped dump

Tags: server, mysql, database, zip

Till now I've created and zipped mysql dumps this way:

```
mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases > /var/www/html/db-$(date +\%F-\%T).sql
zip /var/www/html/db-$(date +\%F-\%T).zip /var/www/html/db-*.sql
rm /var/www/html/db-*.sql
```

Is there a way to have it zipped directly from `mysqldump` and save these 2 extra rows?

Comment: Why? If this is working for you, why change anything?

Comment: If I can get the same result in less code (and you sure know I can), and the code is not complicated, I'd humbly prefer that, at least in this case... The original code was actually part of much longer code I already reviewed and changed.

Comment: Another reason to use the answer below is it can save on disk IO (no need to write out the temporary file, if you pipe it straight to zip)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases | zip /var/www/html/db-$(date +\%F-\%T).zip
```

You will only have one file into the zip archive having **-** as file name.

Comment: Don't work for me (Ubuntu 14.04). Error: "mysqldump: Got errno 32 on write". It's work only if I add `-` at the end.

Answer (score 9):

The other two answers have already stated the following solution (so consider this an extension of the other two answers):

```
mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases | zip /var/www/html/db-$(date +\%F-\%T).zip -
```

This is good, but this works only on stdin/stdout. This means that the file will be stored as `-` inside the archive, and can only *normally* be extracted sanely to stdin. This means to actually extract this data from the ZIP, you will have to do this:

```
unzip -p myZipFile.zip > myBackup.sql
```

If you want to make a "normal" ZIP file (where things have a real name), you will have to do [some really complicated things](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2019603) or just do what you're already doing so there's no net gain.

As MySQL itself  is stdin-aware, you can restore directly from a backup using the below command (as an example):

```
unzip -p myDataBackup.zip | mysql -uroot -pMyInsecurePassword
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases | zip /var/www/html/db-$(date +\%F-\%T).zip -
```

Comment: Why is the ` -` right after `.zip`?

Comment: it the file name in the zip file ... I tried it with another name but without success

Comment: Oh. maybe by chance you tried this on a mac (even though we're on AskUbuntu)? :)

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu20 ">" sign was needed between zip and /var..

```
mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases | zip > /var/www/html/db-$(date +\%F_%H-%M-%S).zip
```